# How to add outer div to Profile2 profile including link set in #prefix

Tags: theming, users

I would like to add a wrapper div around Profile2 profiles when displayed on the user account page. I can wrap the title and profile fields by modifying user-profile-category.tpl.php in my theme. However, there's an anchor link to each profile added in profile2.module using `hook_user_view`: `'#prefix' => '<a id="profile-' . $profile->type . '"></a>',`.

I can't find a template that will allow me to wrap that link along with its accompanying profile. How can I theme those items together?

Answer (score 0):

The Profile2 modules implements a profile2_form_alter hook that you can implement in a module. Say you have a module called kelley_profile2, then the function you want to implement is

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_profile2_form_alter().
 */
function kelley_profile2_form_profile2_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Check profiles key exists in $form_state.
  if (array_key_exists('profiles', $form_state)) {
    // Iterate through each profile type and add prefix.
    foreach ($form_state['profiles'] as $type => $profile) {
      $form['profile_' . $type]['#prefix'] = '<a id="profile-' . $type . '"></a>';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm not sure that you understood the question I was asking. The function you suggested adds a prefix line that has already been added by Profile2. What I want to do is to wrap both that prefix and the content of the profile in an outer div.

Comment: You're right I misunderstood, and didn't realize that profile2 had a user_view hook that added an a name tag. Sorry about that! I think your best option is to use hook_user_view_alter to change the array structure before it renders.